# The while loop is changing intended values for unknown reason

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

I'm new to coding and was working on making a condition for an array, but the while loop condition I've set up for some reason changes the array when it shouldn't have. I'm sorry if this is something obvious, but I couldn't seem to find an question here that applied to my problem.

The code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//================================================================
public class ArrayIrreg {
//----------------------------------------------------------------
    private static Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
        char group, rLetter;

        int num     = 10; // for test
        int rows    = 10;
        int columns =  8;

        // creating 2d array


        System.out.print("Please enter number of rows               : ");
        rows = Keyboard.nextInt();

        while (rows < 0 || rows >= 10) {
            System.out.print("ERROR:Out of range, try again              : ");
            rows = Keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        double[][] figures = new double[rows + 1][num];

        for(int t = 0; t < rows; t++) {
            rLetter = (char)((t)+(int)'A');
            System.out.print("Please enter number of positions in row " + rLetter + " : ");
            columns = Keyboard.nextInt();

            while(columns < 0 || columns >= 8) {
                System.out.print("ERROR:Out of range, try again              : ");
                columns = Keyboard.nextInt();
            }

            for(int j = 0; j <= columns; j++) {
                figures[j] = new double[j] ;
            }

        }

        // filling the array
        for(int row = 0; row < figures.length; ++row) {
            for(int col = 0; col < figures[row].length; ++col) {
                figures[row][col] = 0.0;
            }
        }

        // printing the array
        for(int row = 0; row < figures.length; ++row) {    
            // printing data row
            group = (char)((row)+(int)'A');
            System.out.print(group + " : ");

            for(int col = 0; col < figures[row].length; ++col) {    
                System.out.print(figures[row][col] + " ");
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }

        // printing final border
        for(int col = 0; col < figures[0].length; ++col) {
            System.out.print("-+");
        }

        System.out.println("  ");
    }
}
```

It displays correctly the first time when the values enter are with in the condition the while loop holds, but once the while loop is entered and the value is corrected, the code comes back with different errors or displays the wrong amount.

I'm not sure why it would cause the result to change, since the while loop was intended to force new inputted values if the initial input is out of intended range.

Comment: Time to learn about debugging. Print some stuff (variables, flow control), and read the errors/stack traces you get. They come with line numbers. It might be overkill to use an actual debugger, but that's also very useful to learn.

Comment: It seems to work for me. Can you be more specific than _comes back with different errors or displays the wrong amount_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `Keyboard.nextLine()` after each `Keyboard.nextInt()`.

Explanation: After the scanner calls nextInt() it gets the first value and leaves the rest of the string to the `\n`. We then consume the rest of the string with `nextLine()`.